# Can't edit a question?

Tags: support, retagging

[Why do plants have green leaves and not red?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/450/why-do-plants-have-green-leaves-and-not-red)

For some reason, despite being able to do so for every other question I have come across (including others posted just before) I am unable to edit this post (or even to re-tag it).  Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this would be?

Also, can someone from the community who isn't having problems re-tag the post as appropriate?

Comment: The links are still there for questions posted *after* this one too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that means there is an existing suggested edit on that post, you can't submit a second edit then.

Comment: This is correct.